# Why is the FormPaint event triggered mutilple times when mouse is moved over a TButton

Tags: delphi, windows-10, delphi-xe8

Why is the Form's `OnPaint` event triggered so many times in this application?

1. Create a new VCL Forms Application with two `TButton` controls, one `TMemo` control, and one `TBitBtn` control.
2. Use this code:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     Memo1.Lines.Clear;
   end;

   procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     Memo1.Lines.Add('FormPaint');
   end;
   ```
3. Run the application.

When the mouse is moved onto a `TButton`, the `OnPaint` event is triggered 4 times, and 4 times when the mouse is moved out from the `TButton`.

When the mouse is moved onto a `TBitBtn`, the `OnPaint` event is triggered 3 times, and 3 times when the mouse is moved out from the `TBitBtn`.

When the style is changed in "Project/Options/Application/Appearance" to e.g. "Luna", I will get this behavior instead:

When the mouse is moved onto a `TButton`/`TBitBtn`, the `OnPaint` event is triggered 1 time, and 2 times when the mouse is moved out from the `TButton`/`TBitBtn`.

Why the inconsistency?

Is it possible to avoid the `OnPaint` event when the mouse is moved over a `TButton`?

I have XE8 Subscription Update 1 (and Windows 10).

Comment: Why does it matter to you? If this is a problem, then you likely need to fix a design error elsewhere in your code.

Comment: This is a simple application with a straight-forward question about basic Delphi functionalty. I am curious about the behaviour and differences. That's why it matters to me.

Comment: OnPaint is called because the form's window received a WM_PAINT message. It received that because part of the window is invalid. Why is it a problem for you to paint your window? That's the real issue. FWIW, without the presence of VCL styles, this is not a Delphi question. Rather it's a winapi question.

Comment: The question was why the event is triggered multiple times, in this case 4 times, instead of once. If it is not a Delphi questions, would I get the same result with e.g. C#?

Comment: My point is that the system is sending the Windows messages that lead to the `OnPaint` event being fired. Would you get the same result in C#? That depends on which UI framework you used, and how that framework implements its controls. WPF doesn't use windowed controls, and WinForms doesn't use the Win32 `BUTTON` control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hover over effect of the buttons is responsible for what you observe. When you hover over a button, it changes appearance. When you move the cursor away from the button, it reverts its appearance. Each change of appearance leads to the form's `OnPaint` event being fired. That is just how the underlying painting system works. In order to paint the child control, a `WM_PRINTCLIENT` message is delivered to the control's parent, and that in turn leads to the form's `OnPaint` event firing.

You can see that this is the case by disabling runtime themes. When you do that, moving the cursor over the buttons does not cause `OnPaint` to be fired.

The reason that VCL styles and Windows themes lead to different numbers of `OnPaint` events being fired is simply that they handle the painting in different ways. But VCL styles also has hover over effects, and they also lead to `OnPaint` events being fired.

> Is it possible to avoid the `OnPaint` event when the cursor is moved over a button?

In a VCL styled app you could probably use a VCL style that did not have any hover effects. In a Windows themed app you could disable the theme for the button.

I suspect that the solution to your real problem, the answer to your un-asked question, is to stop using `OnPaint` for whatever you are using it for at present. Instead do whatever you do there in a more appropriate place.